# How to protect a python script in LinuxLite from copying

Tags: python

I have LinuxLite on SD-card of my Raspberry. A Python script 'myscript.py' autorunning after Linux Lite boot. I want anybody can't see the code of the script and can't  copy this file from the SD-Card to other devices or other SD-Cards.

Comment: use encryption, it will make copying much more difficult, but not impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://nuitka.net/ which compiles python scripts into binaries (using C++ as an intermediary language).

Comment: Nuitka file can't be copied? It can't be read?

Comment: It can be copied and read but it cannot be reverse engineered to get your python source code. If you want to protect you code against someone who has physical access to your device I don't think it's possible.